# What is the difference between "git cherry-pick --continue" and "git commit"?

Tags: git

If cherry-pick runs into conflicts, git prompts to do `git cherry-pick --continue`

```
You are currently cherry-picking commit 71e26b4f.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git cherry-pick --continue")
  (use "git cherry-pick --abort" to cancel the cherry-pick operation)

Changes to be committed:

        modified:   app/file1.ts
        modified:   app/file2.ts
```

At this point, we can just also do `git commit`.

So what is the difference(s) between `git cherry-pick --continue` and `git commit`?

Comment: `cherry-pick` calls `commit`

Comment: Emphasis on "at this point". Yes, in *this* context both commands end up doing the same.

Comment: to answer your question *So what is the difference(s) between git cherry-pick --continue and git commit* well they do **totally different things** but `cherry-pick` runs `commit` at the end.

Comment: @Liam your last comment is, in fact, an answer. You should develop it into a real answer, the purpose of comments is to ask for clarifications, not to provide answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `git cherry-pick` command *can* be instructed to cherry-pick multiple commits.

If you had done so, and were in the middle of fixing a conflict on an *early* commit, then:

```
git commit
```

would finish *that* cherry-pick without continuing the remainder of them, while:

```
git cherry-pick --continue
```

would first commit (and thus finish) *that* cherry-pick, then continue the remainder of them—possibly stopping with another merge conflict again in a later one.

In short, if you're only cherry-picking one commit, "finish this one and go on to the rest" produces the same result as "finish this one", but if not, they do not.

(This is a general theme in various Git commands that operate on more than one commit, with the most common other case being `git rebase`—which is essentially a series of cherry-picks!  In modern Git, both commands use what Git calls the *sequencer*, but relatively recently, rebase was a complicated set of shell scripts.)